# Медленное скачивание файлов с ftp посредством python+ftplib

Tags: python, ftp, download

Требуется регулярно проверять ftp сервер на наличие новых файлов и закачивать последние.

Проблема в том, что при небольших размерах файлов (2-15 кб), программе требуется по 10-15 секунд на выполнение куска кода, связанного со скачиванием каждого файла. Все остальные части программы выполняются на порядок быстрее.

Вот часть, отвечающая за скачивание:

```
lf = open(local_filename, "wb")
print ("opened")
try:
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR "+name, lf.write) 
    print ("wrote")
except ftplib.error_perm:
    pass
lf.close()
print ("closed")
```

Значительная пауза происходит между выводом opened и wrote, программа задумывается секунд на 10, что приводит к непозволительно большому времени на скачивание всех файлов, количество которых превышает 3 млн.

Можно ли оптимизировать этот код, чтобы скачивание происходило быстрее?

Comment: вы уверены, что дело не в буферизации вывода (добавьте `sys.stdout.flush()`)? Запустите с `strace` и/или дебаггере и посмотрите на что 10 секунд уходит (dns или, например, если `getaddrinfo()` возвращает несколько ip, а сервис работает только на одном из них (по остальным timeout происходит)). Можно [`multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` использовать, чтобы несколько файлов сразу скачивать](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16501351/4279) (вместо `.map()` используйте `.imap()` если у Вас миллион файлов).

Comment: Пробовали скачивать в несколько потоков?